# Import maven project error in mac: 'project was marked as readonly'

Tags: eclipse, maven

I import the maven project into eclipse, but it display errors like the following:

```
project was marked as readonly
```

But I have not found the .PROJECT file,  what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to project folder through console (cmd in windows, terminal in linux) 
type

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Press Enter.

If it is web application,
type

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Press Enter.

Delete the project (not physically) from eclipse and reimport.